# C++ coding style

Tags: c++, coding-style

not sure if my question suits all rules for StackOverflow question, but I think it will be helpful for future users.

Now I need to choose coding style for a few C++ projects where I'm participating. These projects are big enough and there will be a few programmers working on every. So we need to equalize our code style. Also we want to choose coding style which is *socially acceptable*, so first I'll tell what we already decided to have. My question is, if some of our choices is not *socially unaccepted* and also what are others commonly using C++ coding style rules.

So here what we chosen:

## File naming

Start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores, no spaces).

For example:

```
VeryImportantClass.h
VeryImportantClass.cpp
```

## Namespace naming

Start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores, no spaces). Also alignment should be appropriate.

For example:

```
namespace Drinks
{
    namespace AlcoholDrinks
    {

    }
}
```

## Namespace structure

In header file the have only functions/methods prototypes, realization in `cpp` file, avoid using `using namespace` for realization file.

Example:

```
//header
namespace CommonStuff
{
    namespace SystemParameters
    {
        bool IfWindows();
        //some more stuff...
    }
}

//cpp file
namespace CommonStuff
{
    namespace SystemParameters
    {
        bool IfWindows()
        {
            //some stuff...
            return ...;
        }
    }
}
```

## Classes and structures naming

Start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores, no spaces). No *C* like class prefix or *S* like struct prefix. We decided - it is just more typing.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{

};

struct MyStruct
{

};
```

## class or struct

In some cases it is difficult to understand if we need class or struct. If structure just keep some grouped data - it is `struct`. If structure keeps data and has methods - it is `class`. Exceptional methods are constructor, destructor and comparison operators.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void SetValue(int value);
    int GetValue();
    void PrintValue();
private:
    int m_value;
};

struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct();
    ~MyStruct();    
    int value;
};
```

## Type names

Start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores).

For example:

```
typedef std::string String;
typedef std::vector<String> StringVector;
```

## Variable types

Use our own predefined types, we have:

```
typedef std::string String;
typedef std::vector<String> StringVector;
typedef unsigned char Byte;
typedef std::vector<Byte> ByteVector;
//etc.
```

## Variable naming

Start with a lower letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores).

Example:

```
String messageLicenseExpired = "Your product version is expired, please...";
int importantNumber = 13;
```

## Class variables naming

Starts with prefix **m_** then word starts with a lower letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores).

Example:

```
int m_myVariable;
int m_otherVariable;
```

## Constants

Use all capitals with underscores.

Example:

```
const String PRODUCT_NAME = "our product";
const Byte IMPORTANT_NUMBER = 13;
```

## Constants or preprocessor

If value will be checked using `#ifdef` or some others, then it must be preprocessor definition. Otherwise it is `const`.

For example:

```
#define FAILURE_FACTOR_FOR_DEBUG 50
const int MAGIC_NUMBER = 5;

//some code...

String newString = someString.substr(MAGIC_NUMBER);

//some code...

//not the best example, but I think it is understandable.
#ifdef _DEBUG
    int someValue = FAILURE_FACTOR_FOR_DEBUG;
#else
    int someValue = 0;
#end
```

## Function and methods naming

Start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (no underscores).

For example:

```
int CalculateSometing (int n);
void ToUpper (String& someStr);
```

## Braces

Braces should always go into new line, except initializing.

Example:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
if (arr[0] > 10)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

## else

`else` belongs to new line, see previous example.

## if statement and braces

Even single code line after `if` or `else` should be enclosed.

Example:

```
if (someInt > 100)
{
    someInt = 100;
}
else
{
    someInt /= 2;
}
```

## Methods calling

No space around arrow and dot.

Example:

```
Object obj;
Object* oPtr = new Object();

obj.Method();
obj->Method();
```

## Header files

1. use `#pragma once` in stead of define guards. (`#pragma once` is not standart so in some compilers define guards are must)
2. One header for one class only.
3. Header files only for definitions. Execution instructions must be in related `cpp` file even if it getter or setter. It is because changes in header leads into long compiling.

## Pointers and references

Use reference instead of pointer if it is possible. If possible pass parameter as a reference (for objects), prefer to pass as a `const` reference if value will not be changed.

Example:

```
String ToUpper(String str);           //bad
String ToUpper(String& str);          //better
String ToUpper(const String& str);    //best
void ToUpper(String& str);            //also solution
```

## Error handling

If function may fail, it must return `bool` value `true` for success and `false` for failure. For classes method `GetLastError()` is a must. For function that may fail error code should be returned through additional parameter, e.g. `bool Function(int param, int* errorCode = NULL)` Also we decided not to use exceptions in our code.

## class structure

In header file first public methods (constructors and destructors at the top of them), protected methods, protected variables, private methods, private variables. No public variables, use getters and setters.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    int GetPrivateValue();
    void SetPrivateValue(int value);
    int GetProtectedValue();
    void SetProtectedValue(int value);
protected:
    void SomeMethod();
    int m_protectedValue;
private:
    void SomePrivateMethod();
    int m_privateValue;
};
```

## Formatting

1. Alignment use 4 spaces or tab.
2. Long line wrapping, no longer lines then 120 symbols.

## Self documenting code

Comments are always welcome but the best choice is to give name for variables and functions which explains everything.

Example:

```
void Function (const String& str, const String& str2, StringVector& vect);   //very bad

//This functions tokenize string, str is input string, str2 is delimiters string, vect output
void Function (const String& str, const String& str2, StringVector& vect);    //quite bad

void Tokenize (const String& inputString, const String& delimiters, StringVector& output);    //good, anyway comments using this declaration also welcome.
```

## & and * position

Write `&` and `*` just after variable type.

Example:

```
String* strPtr;
String& strRef;
```

It is all we decided to use, the question is, haven't we missed something? Also, is there anything *globally unacceptable*?

Feel free to comment and ask if something is not clear, why we chosen some.

Hope it will be helpful for latter readers.

Comment: I haven't read everything, but I'll point out that using a capital first left for variables is not standard. It makes them difficult to distinguish from classes. Usual standard is lowercase start then camelCase

Comment: Also your last comment, I recently switched to `String* ptr` style. There are no arguments against it as long as you never initialise multiple variables in one line (something which I consider bad style in most cases anyway)

Comment: As for error handling, unless you're opposed to exceptions (understandable) use them. No point having special error parameters and last error methods when a catch will suffice.

Comment: Most of these can be argued quite reasonably (even if it is to say there's no particular reason to use one over the other), but really, don't use any type that's not yours? Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Having a consistent coding style is a good. My only guideline to other is to have macros UPPERCASE_LETTERS and reserve that for macros, only.

Comment: You need to consider how templates will fit with this style. You also need to consider how you will wrap long lines (if you will wrap long lines)

Comment: By the way, if you're unsure, there's a nice [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) link at the top with [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) listed very early. Clearly stated in there are the following: *Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* and *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.*

Comment: Braces is entirely personal opinion. My view is that I hate braces getting their own line (wasteful), but I strongly agree with braces around single statements

Comment: "4 spaces or tab" is a bad idea. Some people have tab as 8 spaces. All IDEs allow you to set their default, so require one. Personally I use tabs, because that's what tab is for, sometimes with spaces afterwards for alignment

Comment: "Header only for definitions". Hmm, this is probably a point where I diverge from popular opinion but; put simple getters in there and mark them inline. It's becoming less of an issue with link-time optimisation but that's still new and buggy in my experience.

Comment: Using getters and setters for every single data member defeats the whole purpose of a class.

Comment: Did you have a **question**? You know, a sentence ending with a question mark, as opposed to a treatise.

Comment: @chris Not at all, and having no public data members is highly recommended by nearly all authorities.

Comment: @JimBalter, I'm complaining about getters and setters for every data member. Imagine if you could set a `std::vector`'s internal pointer to whatever you wanted? It defeats encapsulation with every bit of code being able to access every data member, and it especially defeats abstraction, since a lot of data members shouldn't need to be worried about at all, let alone manipulated from outside of the class.

Comment: Regarding the "Self documenting code" section -- in addition to names for variables and functions I would also add a strong emphasis for well-named types, see: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UseTheStaticTyping, http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf#page=18

Comment: I'd also take a look at the existing documents, e.g., http://www.appinf.com/download/CppCodingStyleGuide.pdf

Comment: @chris "I'm complaining about getters and setters for every data member" -- Well silly you ... the OP only requires them for *public* data. " Imagine if you could set a std::vector's internal pointer to whatever you wanted? " -- setters don't have to be public; they are subject to access protection just like data members, so the notion that *setters per se* violate encapsulation is absurd, foolish, and ignorant -- it. But that's not what the OP mentioned; read and comprehend: "No **public** variables, use getters and setters."

Comment: That was supposed to be "-- it's **public access to private data** that violates encapsulation" ... and that is not what the OP suggested, as just a modicum of reading and thinking makes clear.

Comment: @JimBalter, I took it to mean public setters and getters for all data members, just like in the example. Typically, when this happens, most of them end up just doing what a public data member would anyway. If that's the case, there's no reason for there to always be access to all data members. It really hurts a level of abstraction when the data member shouldn't matter to the user. Perhaps the main difference between us is our interpretation of the guideline.

Comment: @JimBalter, I'm not particularly opposed to them replacing members that would be public, nor only using them internally within the class like you said, but articles like [this](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) and [this](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) better explain what my problem is.

Comment: @chris In my view your problem is, or was, a failure to have read or comprehended what the OP wrote. As a response to those articles, I offer the Scala language, in which everything, including functions, is an object, and all data members automatically have associated getters and, if mutable (declared with `var` rather than `val`), setters.

Comment: @chris "just like in the example" -- I apologize, I overlooked that in the example. It appears to me to be  a typo, placing those getters and setters in the wrong section. I really do hope so; I would not like to think that anyone is so stupid as to *intend* a standard of having public getters and setters for protected and private data members.

Comment: @JimBalter, Honestly, I've never seen a public interface for a protected variable and I can't think of a reason to want one :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many coding standards available by respected institutions:

Here is a good one  https://wiki.ucar.edu/download/attachments/25039241/european_space_agency_standards.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this should be an answer or a comment. I'll post as an answer so it's easier for others to comment on this.

I am no big fan of indenting namespaces as you propose. Some projects can have quite deep 
nesting levels for namespaces, which really makes the code unreadable.

Comment: I usually indent only my `detail` namespace, and that's with no short line length limit, just my screen width or so.